# Microsoft Graph mail send body with placeholders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send email to multiple recipients using microsoft graph and I want to use placeholders such as first name, last name, username and these placeholders to be replaced for each recipient. Is this possible and how can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible programmatically. Refer to the below C# sample that works.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var messageBody = String.Format("Dear {0}, The new cafeteria is open at {1}", "user1", "floor1");
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
        Content = messageBody
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    },
    CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    }
};

var saveToSentItems = false;

await graphClient.Me
    .SendMail(message,saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: the aim is in the string "Dear {0}, The new cafeteria is open at {1}" {0} and {1} to be replaced for each recipient. Let's assume that in you solution fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com has name fannyd and danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com has name danas what I want to achieve is one email content to be  "Dear fannyd , The new cafeteria is open at fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" and the other to be "Dear danas, The new cafeteria is open at danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"

Comment: Use a loop and dynamically form the message body , message and use that to send mail for every iteration.